# R Packages installed version numbers

Tags: r, package

I'm trying to sync the packages between Dev and Prod Environment for our client.
For that I need to look up for all the packages installed in both the Environments.

To check for all the packages installed I ran the following command :

```
installed.packages(fields=c("Package","Version"))
```

However, when I run this command I don't get the version of the packages.
I just get the version of R Installed.

See Screenhshot :
[image]

Also if I try to run the below command then it will give me the version for individual package:

```
packageDescription("packageName")$Version
```

Can someone help me here with the command so that I can get all the packages installed in R (through Putty command line) with their respective versions so that I can copy those values in excel and compare them?

Comment: Your screenshot conveniently cuts off the table header that would have made it clear that you’re showing the “Build” version, not the package version (which is also there, you’re just not showing it in the screenshot).

Comment: Hello Sorry i coudnt show it in the screenshot but believe me thats the Build of R and not the Package Version

Comment: Yes, that’s what my comment is saying. The R package version is shown elsewhere in the table. Scroll up.

Answer (score 5):

`installed.packages` will always return the package version, in the `Version` column.

```
pkgs <- installed.packages()
vers <- pkgs[, "Version"]
```

This will be a character vector, which is a tad inconvenient if you want to compare versions. The `package_version` function will turn a character string like "3.3.2" into an object that is more suitable for the task.

```
package_version(vers["stats"])
# '3.3.2'

package_version(vers["stats"]) > package_version("3.1")
# TRUE

package_version(vers["stats"]) == packageVersion("stats")  # note function names
# TRUE
```

Comment: When i run just installed.packages i get the following error  :


function (lib.loc = NULL, priority = NULL, noCache = FALSE, fields = NULL, 
    subarch = .Platform$r_arch) 
{
    if (is.null(lib.loc)) 
        lib.loc <- .libPaths()
    if (!is.null(priority)) {
        if (!is.character(priority)) 
            stop("'priority' must be character or NULL")

Answer (score 0):

This will give a complete table of loaded packages and versions. Just ready to run in the R environment. (Sorry I just noticed the requested answer was through the putty command line).

```
Packages <- data.frame()
for(i in 1:(length((.packages())))){
  package <-(.packages())[i]
  version <- packageVersion(package)
  PV <- data.frame(package, version)
Packages <- rbind(Packages,PV)
    }
Packages
```